# NSPredicate not working

Tags: iphone, ios, regex, search, nspredicate

I have this string:
`<td align="right"><span>&nbsp;19:45&nbsp;</span></td>`

I want to use a NSPredicate on it to search for the 19:45 part but every possible combination I tried returns nothing! I'm kinda losing my marbles here so please help!

Things i've tried:

```
NSString *timeStringPredicate = @"[0-9]:[0-9]";
NSPredicate *timeSearch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like %@", timeStringPredicate];

if ([timeSearch evaluateWithObject:dayText]) {
NSLog(@"This is a time");
}
```

Or in these possibilities:

```
NSString *timeStringPredicate = @"[0-9]\\:[0-9]";
NSString *timeStringPredicate = @"*[0-9]:[0-9]*";
NSString *timeStringPredicate = @"*[0-9]\\:[0-9]*";
NSString *timeStringPredicate = @"*.[0-9]:[0-9].*";
NSString *timeStringPredicate = @"*.[0-9]\\:[0-9].*";
```

And about everything else.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`like` doesn't use regexp syntax.  For that, you need to use `matches` instead.  See [The Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868) for details.

`NSString *timeStringPredicate = @".*\\:[0-9].*";`

`NSPredicate *timeSearch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF matches %@", timeStringPredicate];`

Comment: I read the Programming guide. But in my honest opinion. Apple isn't the very best at providing clear examples. I tried MATCHES too and the only thing that happens than is crash. What would the correct syntax be for the MATCHES statement?

Comment: No, but unfortunately that's what it does... The moment I switch the statement to MATCHES it doesn't get past the NSPredicate part. No error message.. just exit...

Comment: `NSString *timeStringPredicate = @".*\\:[0-9].*";
            NSPredicate *timeSearch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF matches %@", timeStringPredicate];` This was it...

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
NSString *timeStringPredicate = @".*\\:[0-9].*";
NSPredicate *timeSearch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF matches '%@'", timeStringPredicate];
```